# Java,Reiniciar un Objeto

Tags: java

El problema es que cuando  abro por primera vez funciona bien ,selecciono el ítem del `JComboBox` y me lo marca ,como debe ser y luego cierra la ventana (sin terminar el programa ya que esa ventana es secundaria) con el botón cerrar  pero el problema es cuando abro otra vez la ventana: el `JComboBox` me marca la opción que elige previamente (soy principiante en esto, pero por lo que pude entender cuando cierro la ventana ,los objetos me siguen funcionando en segundo plano ,no sé la forma de terminar esos objetos). Yo estaba buscando una forma de que cuando abro otra vez la ventana esos objetos se reinicien y empiecen otra vez.

Esto es el código con un objeto (son varios objetos en la misma ventana pero creo que con un objeto de muestra ya ayudará como ejemplo):

Este código llama al objeto-

```
package Antes; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import Constantes.Pantallas; 

public class Antes_Control extends JPanel{
/** * */ 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public static Pantallas Pantalla=new Pantallas();
  public void Accion_Control() {
    // PANTALLA 
    Pantalla.Pantalla_ventana();
    // LAMINA 
    JPanel LD=new JPanel(); 
    JPanel LB=new JPanel();
    LB.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    LD.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0)); 
    // JComboBox
    ObjetoJComboBox Lista=new ObjetoJComboBox();
    Lista.Accion_Lista();
    LD.add(Lista);
// BOTONES CERRAR
    Botones terminar=new Botones(); 
    terminar.Botones_Final();
    LB.add(terminar);
// CONFIGURACION DE LA PANTALLA
    Pantalla.add(LD); 
    Pantalla.add(LB,BorderLayout.SOUTH); Pantalla.setVisible(true); 
  }

  public void Cerrar_Control() { 
    Pantalla.setVisible(false);
    Pantalla.dispose();
  } 
}
```

-el boton que cierra la ventana-

```
package Antes;
import javax.swing.*;
class Botones extends JPanel{
/** * */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public void Botones_Final() {
    // CREACION DE LOS BOTONES 
    JButton cerrar=new JButton("cerrar"); 
    // ACCION DE LOS BOTONES
    cerrar.addActionListener(new Accion_cerrar());
    // AGREGAMOS TODO
    add(cerrar);
  }

  class Accion_cerrar implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Antes_Control Cerrar=new Antes_Control(); 
      Cerrar_.Cerrar_Control();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Agrega algo de tu código para saber donde esta el posible error, Saludos!

Comment: Si es una ventana modal cada vez que la cierres puedes destruirla usando el metodo dispose y asi que cuando la vuelvas a abrir haga un reset, esto es a grandes razgos igual como menciono @ChrisVazquez intenta proporcionar algo de codigo para asesorarte de mejor manera.

Comment: le dejo un fragmento del codigo

Comment: @GuillermoAndria podrías ser más concreto y añadir lo justo y necesario para poder reproducir tu problema. Te dejo aquí un enlace para ver como crear un [ejemplo minimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Aritzbn muchas gracias por tu consejo , intente sacar todo lo innecesario , espero que lo entiendan , cualquier consejo es bien recibido